# Odoo many2many checkboxes select all by default

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I want to have all checkboxes selected by default

I have already asked this question on odoo.com but the answer I got was to set this lambda function to default:

```
event_booth_ids = fields.Many2many('event.booth', string='Stände', default=lambda self: self.env['event.booth'].search([('id', '=', 2)]))
```

Unfortunately tho, this does not appear to be working since all checkboxes are still unselected.

What would also work if there was a button to select all.
I just need a way to select all at once.

Also, only the records in the domain(This is what it looks like in the view)

```
<field name="event_booth_ids" widget="many2many_checkboxes" domain="[('halle_id', '=', halle_id)]"/>
```

should be selected

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo will [automatically check](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/fields/relational_fields.js#L3092-L3094) the many2many values

To make all checkboxes checked set the value `event_booth_ids` to all `event.booth` records (filtered by `domain`)

You can test it by setting the value of the many2many field when the value of `halle_id` changes

***Example:***

```py
@api.onchange('halle_id')
def _onchange_halle_id(self):
    if self.halle_id:
        self.event_booth_ids = self.env['event.booth'].search([('halle_id', '=', self.halle_id.id)])
```

All records assigned to the `event_booth_ids` field (returned by the search method) should be checked.

Comment: Can you give me a more concrete example, I'm not sure how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: I added a simple example, that searches for event booth records filtered by the `halle_id` field and assigns them to the `event_booth_ids`